# Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, class

I am following this sample [`Create bar chart`](http://phloxblog.in/angulard3/start.html#N), but there is an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined`.

I have included the library for prototype.js

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

Here is the code,

**HTML**:

```
<div id="d3area" angulard3-ear-chart datajson="'sample.json'" xaxis-name = "" xaxis-pos= "" yaxis-name="'Price/($)'" yaxis-pos="12" d3-format="'%d-%b%y'"
```

And directive,

**App.Js**:

```
var BarGraph = Class.create({
initialize: function(datajson,xaxisName,xaxisPos,yaxisName,yaxisPos,d3Format) {
this.datajson = datajson;
this.xaxisName = xaxisName;
this.xaxisPos = xaxisPos;
this.yaxisName = yaxisName;
this.yaxisPos = yaxisPos;
this.d3Format = d3Format;
},
workOnElement: function(element) {

},
```

Comment: yes, where did you defined the Class?

Comment: i am just following the sample i mentioned, is it necessary to define the class? if so how?

Comment: Class is something that Prototype.js defines. It should be available after file is loaded, so it being undefined means that it isn't yet loaded when you try to use it already.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: If you consider my answer correct, please accept it below! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in a comment, you should wait until everything (including Prototype.js) is loaded. This can be done as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_lib_prototype.asp). Basically tie your code's execution to onload event.